# Visualize difference between members of the list

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization

I want to visualize the difference between members of a set:

```
set = {20, 36, 70, 96, 152, 301}
```

This way I get the diffs:

```
diffs = Select[#[[2]] - #[[1]] & /@ Tuples[{set, set}], # > 0 &]

{16, 50, 76, 132, 281, 34, 60, 116, 265, 26, 82, 231, 56, 205, 149}
```

But how can I put the diffs as a caption over graph like lines between members?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Borrowing some code from Kuba's:

```
set = {20, 36, 70, 96, 152, 301}
Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ #,
   VertexShapeFunction -> "Square",
   VertexSize -> {.2, .1},
   VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
   VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Arial", 10], 
   GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding",
   EdgeLabels -> ((DirectedEdge[##] -> Placed[#2 - #, .85]) & @@@ #)] &@Subsets[set, {2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

In fact, you could apply any nice formatting to the edges. The following applies a color proportional to its value:

```
set = {20, 36, 70, 96, 152, 301};
{min, max} = {Min@#, Max@#} &[Subtract @@@ -Subsets[set, {2}]]
Graph[Property[DirectedEdge @@ #, 
               EdgeStyle -> {Thick, ColorData["Rainbow"][
                             Rescale[#[[2]] - #[[1]], {min, max}]]}] & /@ #,
   VertexShapeFunction -> "Square",
   VertexSize -> {.2, .1},
   VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
   VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Arial", 10], 
   GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding", 
   EdgeLabels -> ((DirectedEdge[##] -> Placed[#2 - #, .85]) & @@@ #)] 
 &@Subsets[set, {2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

```
set = {20, 36, 70, 96, 152, 301}

Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ #, EdgeLabels -> ((DirectedEdge[##] -> (#2 - #)) & @@@ #), 
                          VertexLabels -> Thread[set -> set], EdgeLabelStyle -> Bold, 
                          VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 20]
     ] &[Tuples[set, {2}]]
```

[image]

```
 Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ #, EdgeLabels -> ((DirectedEdge[##] -> (#2 - #)) & @@@ #), 
                           VertexLabels -> Thread[set -> set], 
                           EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 15], 
                           GraphLayout -> "StarEmbedding", ImagePadding -> 35, 
                           VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 20]
      ] &[Subsets[set, {2}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I just want one path between two nodes. How can I remove the negative ones?

Comment: @MohsenAfshin You could try `Subsets[set, {2}]` rather than `Tuples...`

Comment: I did, but the visual output is not as readable as what @Kuba rendered, how can I force the circular rendering?

Comment: @MohsenAfshin take a look at `GraphLayout`, e.g `"CircularEmbedding"`